# How to read multiple CSV files in a zip folder using Python

Tags: python

I need to read multiple csv files in a zip folder and extract the data from those csv's into a container in Python.

I am new to Python having basic knowledge.So detailed explanation is appreciable.

Thanks in advance
Sampath

Comment: Please share with us what have you tried ?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to do is to open the zip file using module [`zipfile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html#module-zipfile). Then read the CSV data from each archived file and store it in a container such as a dictionary.

The following will read the data from each file in the zip archive into a dictionary keyed by the file name.

```
import zipfile

container = {}

with zipfile.ZipFile('/path/to/your/zipfile') as zf:
    for name in zf.namelist():
        container[name] = zf.read(name)

for name in container:
    print("Contents of file {}:".format(name))
    print(container[name])
    print("============================\n")
```

Optionally you could process the csv data using module [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#module-csv). Something like this should get you started:

```
import csv
import zipfile
from cStringIO import StringIO

container = {}

with zipfile.ZipFile('/path/to/your/zipfile') as zf:
    for name in zf.namelist():
        container[name] = csv.reader(StringIO(zf.read(name)))
```

Now `container` is a dictionary keyed by file name with `csv.reader` objects as values.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can read all the text inside zip:

```
import zipfile

archive = 'c:\\test\\archive.zip'

def readZip(archive):
    zfile = zipfile.ZipFile(archive)
    for finfo in zfile.infolist():
        ifile = zfile.open(finfo)
        lines = ifile.readlines()
    return lines

print(readZip(archive))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help.

Apart from the code provided above,I have come up with a code which satisfies the question

```
import os
import csv
from zipfile import ZipFile

#Extracts and loads the files in a zip file to a specified destination
ze = ZipFile(open("Src_AdventureWorks_Files.zip","r"))
ze.extractall("/home/sreddi/workspace/DQAS_Main/Src_AdventureWorks_Files/")
print "Extraction successful"


#Meta data of the zipfile
zf = ZipFile('Src_AdventureWorks_Files.zip', 'r')
zc = zf.namelist()
print zc

#Loop to run each csv file and print the data        
    if __name__ == "__main__":             
    i=0            
    while i < len(zc):
        #path = '/home/sreddi/workspace/DQAS_Main/Src_AdventureWorks_Files/'+zc[i]
        #print path
        print zc[i]
        for csv_path in zc:
            print "###########"
            print zc[i]
            print "###########"
            os.chdir('/home/sreddi/workspace/DQAS_Main/Src_AdventureWorks_Files')
            f = open(zc[i])
            csv_f = csv.reader(f)
            for row in csv_f:
                print row
            f.close()
            i += 1
```